# is it possible to scan android bluetooth device using swift corebluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, swift, bluetooth

I wanna build iOS app that scan nearby bluetooth device and get their identifier (maybe Mac address, or anything else), either it's iOS device or android device using Swift CoreBluetooth framework.

When i run the app with my iphone, it can only found my macbook's bluetooth device even my android phone is nearby with bluetooth activated.

Is it possible to scan my android bluetooth using CoreBluetooth ?

*my android phone has BLE

Comment: Broadly, you need to look for a BLE service that is being advertised.  Unless there is an app running on the Android device to advertise a specific BLE service, there is nothing to discover.  However, you should be able to discover the battery service and the device information service.  Start with the LightBlue app from the App Store; If it can see your Android device and your code can't, then there is something wrong with your code; Show your code.

Comment: using LightBlue App from App Store my android bluetooth, it still can't discover my android bluetooth device. so is it impossible to do ?

Comment: If LightBlue can’t find it then there is no service to find. You would need an app running on the android to be discovered.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for the help.